# Binance API - получить текущий курс пары валют P2P

Tags: java, api, binance

Может кто-то уже делал, не для трейдинга, задача самая простая, получить текущий курс пары валют, например: USD-USDT при оплате P2P с выбором определённого типа Куда отправить.

**Например:** Я покупаю USDT, плачу USD продавцу на advcash. Ответ от API - массив или json с текущими курсами предложений

Comment: не совсем понятно, какой ответ вы ожидаете? у бинанса есть нормальная документация здесь https://www.binance.com/en/binance-api , у него есть клиент, доступный здксь https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.openhft.com.binance.api/binance-api-client/2.17.1 и отличное его описание с примерамикода на гите https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api. Куда лучше? если вы пишите код и у вас есть конкретная проблема - давайте код.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Это именно то что нужно. Я, до этого, видимо, левую какую-то библиотеку использовал

Comment: да не за что)))